# Need help in identifying the last character in this image

Tags: characters

I have a license plate from the Heliongijang province. I would like to know what is the last character in this image and how is it pronounced. Also, I have seen many license plates which have this character in the end. So, I would also like to know is this a character that represents the city or is it something else?

> [image]

Comment: The two characters are 黑 (hēi) and 挂 (guà).  Presumably, 黑 is short for 黑龙江 (Hēilóngjiāng).  I'm not sure what 挂 means in the context of a license plate.

Comment: Thanks does gua represent a city/province.

Comment: I don't live in China, but my best guess is that one of the many meanings of 挂 (guà), (ordinarily meaning "to hang"), include "Registered" or 挂号, (Registered Number) So 8173挂 would be "Registered No. 8173"?

Comment: Yes i looked it up gua represents the word suspended.Also bit strange but it seems this would imply that this vehicle has been suspended.In china the vehicle format is as follows: 1)Province 2)Followed by city name 3)Number 4)Vehicle type.It's amazing what an efficient google search can give you.All thanks to becky and wayne.

Comment: thanks for helping me out becky and wayne.

Answer (score 3):

挂车 seems to mean a "trailer". Searching for "挂车号牌" brings up images of trailers, most of which have number plates that end in "挂" (see below). My Chinese is not that great but according to [this document](http://cgs.gzjd.gov.cn/nsyycms/u/cms/www/201310/141301475hqv.pdf) (page 15, item 5.10), trailer number plates are distinguished using the character "挂".

[image]